# Unexpected value 'AngularFirestoreDocument' imported by the module 'AppModule' error

Tags: javascript, angular

Good day developers , im having an issue i have being struggling with the whole day but can't see the problem, the error thrown is :

[image]

Honestly looking the AppComponent at first sight doens't seem to be any remarkable error.Is there by chance any problem with AngularFirestoreDocument and AngularFirestoreCollection im missing?.
Here also leave my app.module.ts scheme.
Thanks in advance

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  AngularFirestoreModule,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';
import { UserSheetComponent } from './components/user-sheet/user-sheet.component';
import { UserSheetBalanceComponent } from './components/user-sheet-balance/user-sheet-balance.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './components/users/users.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './components/signup/signup.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { WelcomePageComponent } from './components/welcome-page/welcome-page.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { LoginService } from './services/LoginService.service';
import { LogOutService } from './services/LogOutService.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/AuthService.service';
import { ControlMessagesComponent } from './components/control-messages/control-messages.component';
import { ValidationService } from './services/ValidationService.service';
import { SignFormService } from './services/SignInFormService.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AddingImportService } from './services/addingImportService.service';
import { authguardian } from './guardians/authguardian.guard';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    UserSheetComponent,
    UserSheetBalanceComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    WelcomePageComponent,
    ControlMessagesComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(
      environment.firebaseConfig,
      'ngExpenseClassifier'
    ),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    FlashMessagesModule,
    AngularFirestoreDocument,
    AngularFirestoreCollection,
  ],
  providers: [
    LoginService,
    LogOutService,
    AuthService,
    ValidationService,
    SignFormService,
    HttpClientModule,
    AddingImportService,
    authguardian,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularFirestoreDocument and AngularFirestoreCollection are not modules! So it cannot be imported at `imports`.

Remove `AngularFirestoreDocument` and `AngularFirestoreCollection`, and try importing `AngularFireDatabaseModule` instead!

```
imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  ]
```

Comment: But guess AngularFireDatabaseModule can't be found in my app dependencies

Comment: Any idea about why is this happening